# Is it possible to create a Windows 7 System Image, to multiple Blu Ray (BD-R) discs? If so, how?

Tags: windows, windows-7, backup, blu-ray, optical-media

Is it possible to create a Windows 7 System Image, using Microsoft's built in Backup and Restore feature, to multiple, write once, Blu Ray (BD-R) optical discs? If so, how?

In Windows 7, when attempting to use the "Create System Image" feature under the Backup and Restore control panel, one of the location options is "On one or more DVDs".

I attempted to use this option using a blank BD=R disc (25GB) with my BD drive.

The process requires that windows "format" the media first and cannot continue if you decline.

After formatting, it always results in an error "Format was not successful".

The only options from there are to keep trying the same thing with the same disk or a new disk or stop the backup.

After some searching, it appears that Windows used to have this same problem with write once DVD-R and DVD+R media as well with many users reporting success only after switching to Re-Writable (RW/RE) media.

I attempted to try a DVD+R as well, and it seemed to have success, but I would prefer to write to two BD-R discs instead of 11 DVDs.

Is this documented anywhere?  Are there any Windows Updates that enable this? Any hotfixes?

Windows is able to utilize the BD drive and discs just fine in Windows Explorer.